# Not a GROUP BY Expression, but why?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm completely confused as to why this code is not a GROUP BY expression:

```
SELECT Section_ID, COUNT(Student_ID) 
FROM Enrollment
WHERE Enroll_Date = TO_DATE('22-FEB-2007', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
GROUP BY Section_ID
ORDER BY Section_ID DESC, Student_ID;
```

I know it has something to do with the COUNT function, but I can't figure out why. Even if I add COUNT(Student_ID) to the GROUP BY I get a different error saying group function isn't allowed here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please rephrase the question. Hard to understand what is being asked here.

Comment: When `GROUP BY` (and UNION/EXCEPT/INTERSECT and SELECT DISTINCT), only select list items may be specified in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Studentid is not now part of the result, so you cannot order by that. You could order by the count values.

Note also. By grouping on section_id there is only one unique row for each of those, so ordering by a second column isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here group by() clause is depend on the columns in select statement and order by () clause depends on grouped columns so we can't sort the column which is not grouped. But in normal select statement we can use the column even if the column is not listed in select statement. Student_id is not grouped,so this error is coming.

so we can use

```
SELECT Section_ID, COUNT(Student_ID) 
FROM Enrollment
WHERE Enroll_Date = TO_DATE('22-FEB-2007', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
GROUP BY Section_ID
ORDER BY Section_ID DESC;
```

or we can use

```
SELECT Section_ID, COUNT(Student_ID) 
FROM Enrollment
WHERE Enroll_Date = TO_DATE('22-FEB-2007', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
GROUP BY Section_ID,Student_ID
ORDER BY Section_ID DESC, Student_ID;
```

But we have no use of this second one.